# How to access all specific versions of a generic static class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, static-methods, static-classes

Let's say I have the following static class:

```
public static class Foo<T>
{
    private static T Baz;

    /* other members */

    public static void Bar()
    {
        //do something with Baz
    }
}
```

Is there a built-in way to call `Bar()` for all specific versions of the generic class without knowing the type parameters that were used? That is, if the consumer of `Foo<T>` has used it as `Foo<Larry>`, `Foo<Curly>` and `Foo<Moe>`, how can I call all the `Foo<Larry>.Bar()`, `Foo<Curly>.Bar()` etc. methods automatically without explicitly specifying the generic types?

Comment: your static class contains a non-static method?

Comment: Your code dosen't compile. And no, it isn't possible.

Comment: This isn't possible.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?  Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: Yes, missed the static declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. Use the static constructor of `Foo<T>` to maintain a global list of `Baz` values. That global list must be rooted in a static variable that lives outside of `Foo<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, I've used the same approach, but wanted to learn if there was a better way.

Comment: Sure, I find your question to be valid.

Comment: @Alexey You could have a `public static readonly List<Action> BarActions` in another (non-generic) class, and just use `static Foo() { OtherClass.BarActions.Add(Bar); }`.

Comment: False. Is possible (and not very difficult). See my answer

Answer (score 0):

The number of possibilities for T is infinite.  There is no way to know what might be used for T.  You can, using the static constructor, track the types that have already been used for T and perform an operation against all of those types.

Here I created a class with a static variable containing a list of Actions.  `Action` matches the signature of `void Bar()`, so to call a different signature, use a different type i.e. `Action<string>` to call `void Bar(string x)` or `Func<int,string>` to call `string Bar(int val)`.

```
public static class FooTracker
{
    public static List<Action> AllBars = new List<Action>();
    public static void CallAllBars()
    {
        AllBars.ForEach(v => v());
    }
}

public static class Foo<T>
{
    static Foo()
    {
        FooTracker.AllBars.Add(() => Bar());
    }

    public static void InitFoo() 
    { 
        // do nothing other than cause static constructor to run
    }


    private static T Baz;

    /* other members */

    public static void Bar()
    {
        //do something with Baz
        Debug.Print(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

If you use the code below to call this, you will observe that `Foo<Curly>.Bar()` isn't called because the static constructor isn't run until after the `CallAllBars()` call.

```
Foo<Larry>.InitFoo();
Foo<Moe>.InitFoo();

FooTracker.CallAllBars();

Foo<Curly>.InitFoo();
```

Comment: Why did you write `FooTracker.AllBars.Add(() => Bar());` instead of `FooTracker.AllBars.Add(Bar);`?

Comment: No reason, just some bad habits of mine.  Functionally it works the same but I think your version compile to better code, although I find my version easier to read.